# BQL Question [New to BQL and programming in general]

Tags: programming, market-data, bloomberg

I have this BQL query to grab a list of Russell 3000 members and get the firm names. Is there any way I can grab other data with the company names such as industry/sector name, total assets, EPS, etc...? If so what is the structure/syntax to do that? I am not new to Excel or modeling just new to Bloomberg. I have a couple years experience in VBA.

=BQL.Query("get(name()) for(members(('RAY Index')))","showheaders=false")

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to the help desk. They have product specialists who will be more than happy to help you out.

Comment: Just a word of caution. BBG imposed some undisclosed daily and monthly limit on your API calls. Since there are no exact details, it's hard to tell how much data it is exactly. However, just querying a few data points for each active option of SPX usually means you are blocked. Granted, the option chain is larger, but not by that much. As long as it doesn't happen frequently, there isn't really an issue apart from not having API until it gets reset. However, it's still annoying when excel doesn't work for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just pass comma-delimited lists of fields to get, as well as filters, like

`=BQL("Filter(Members('RAY Index')`**,**`GICS_SECTOR_NAME=='Fishmongers')", "PX_LAST*100/PX_VOLUME`**,**`RIGHT(NAME,10)`**,**`EXCH_CODE")`

(This is just an example GICS_SECTOR)